# Best way to double check query results are right on large tables

Tags: error-handling

When you write SQL query between big tables what is a good way to check that you have the correct query when the resulting table is 2000+ lines?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately your question is too generalized and broad to be answerable on here. It's going to be situational and depend on what you're trying to query for. It's no different than checking anything else, such as if your application code is working correctly. You'll need to analyze the outputted result, and see if it makes sense for what you're trying to accomplish. The more you work with a particular dataset the more you become intimate and have a better intuitive sense of how things should look like. So time and practice is key here.

I'm not sure if you're saying your query is 2,000+ lines of code or if your result set is 2,000+ records. For the former, similar principals apply in database development as does regular application development and programming. You shouldn't ever have a single query that's 2,000 lines of code long, not even an entity (such as a procedure or function) solely composed of so many lines of code. If you do, then the design of the query is bad form and the implementation is poor. Rather things probably can be simplified, refactored, more smartly written, and broken out into individual entities that logically break up pieces of the code.

For the latter, 2,000 rows of data is not a lot by any means, and should be able to be analyzed if valid by spot checking.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're talking about *ad hoc* SELECT queries, not views or reports. Views and reports (the queries underlying reports) are best verified by a controlled test suite. A controlled test suite would also verify SQL UPDATE and DELETE queries.

If the situation is complex, you might have to build a test suite for an *ad hoc* query.

Having said all that, the best way to verify *ad hoc* queries is to ask a domain expert. Users tell you what business question they need an answer to; you write the SQL; domain experts tell you whether your SQL returned the right rows. (The user might be the domain expert.)

Back in the day, I was the database designer for a database that supported multi-district litigation. One day, an attorney asked me how many open matters there were. The simple and direct answer, which just counted the rows in one table, was the wrong answer. Well, technically, it was the *right* answer, but it lacked nuance. Remarkably few people were interested in *that* definition of *open matter*.

Instead, each interested group had one or more definitions of *open matter* that related directly to the work they were doing. There were a *lot* of groups.

IIRC, over the course of 10 years or so, I identified 19 different definitions of *open matter*. There's absolutely no way I could have determined that the queries were returning the right rows. Only an attorney or paralegal *with extensive experience in that particular litigation* could tell whether the data I provided correctly answered the question "How many open matters are there?"

**Domain experts** are your friends.

Comment: For what I'm doing ideally I should be both the domain expert and database guy

Comment: @bakalolo: If you're the domain expert, and you can't tell whether the query returns the right rows, then you need a controlled test suite. With a controlled test suite, it doesn't matter how many rows a query returns, because code will do the comparison. If the controlled test suite is part of a test database--it probably *should* be--you probably want to insert enough rows to test every known case and every known edge case. Add to the test suite as you learn more.